# load property file using classpath:resources/jdbc.properties

Tags: java, maven, url, classpath

How can I load property file using core java if I execute below command from command line -

```
mvn clean package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.crossover.trial.properties.Main" -Dexec.args="classpath:resources/jdbc.properties"
```

and In class file I use

```
 Properties prop1 = new Properties();
            URL url1 = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("classpath:resources/jdbc.properties");
            try{
                prop1.load(url1.openStream());
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("------- By Using URL class -------");
            System.out.println(prop1);
```

it gives null pointer.

pls suggest

Comment: Did you try without the "classpath:" prefix?

Comment: No I want to have it with classpath uri only. thats the requirement

Comment: by "resources/jdbc.properties" do you mean "src/main/resources/jdbc.properties"?

Comment: @atao - yes. but should be with classpath: uri

Answer (score 0):

exec:java "-Dexec.args=param1 param2 param3"

so in your case exec:java "-Dexec.args=classpath:resources/jdbc.properties"

(look the " " locations) , and you will get classpath:resources/jdbc.properties at args[0] .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide any location on the command line. Or to start the resource name with "classpath:". As you stated in your answer to my previous comment, with the properties file under src/main/resources, maven-jar-plugin will put it inside the jar on the classpath.

This code:

```
package com.crossover.trial.properties;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties prop1 = new Properties();
        URL url1 = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("jdbc.properties");
        try{
            prop1.load(url1.openStream());
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("------- By Using URL class -------");
        System.out.println(prop1);
    }
}
```

will be fine.

It seems that you haven't specified the mainclass in the manifest. To simplify your command line, add it using maven-jar-plugin.

You can also use maven-antrun-plugin to launch it (as I work under Eclipse, I avoid exec-maven-plugin, but otherwise it's only a matter of taste):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <main.class>com.crossover.trial.properties.Main</main.class>

        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>${project.encoding}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.encoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.source>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
        <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>
        <maven.compiler.verbose>true</maven.compiler.verbose>
        <maven.compiler.optimize>true</maven.compiler.optimize>
        <maven.compiler.debug>true</maven.compiler.debug>

        <maven.jar.plugin.version>2.6</maven.jar.plugin.version>
        <maven.antrun.plugin.version>1.8</maven.antrun.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.jar.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jar-launcher</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.antrun.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <java fork="true" jar="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>class-launcher</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.antrun.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <java fork="true" classname="${main.class}">
                                    <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                </java>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Now you can launch your jar with:

```
mvn clean package antrun:run -Pjar-launcher
```

or directly the main class, without packaging:

```
mvn clean compile antrun:run -Pclass-launcher
```

That's it.

## UPDATE

To use exec-maven-plugin, add to the pom:

```
<profile>
    <id>jar-exec</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.exec.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-jar</argument>
                        <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>class-exec</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.exec.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>${main.class}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Now you can launch your jar with:

```
mvn clean package exec:exec -Pjar-exec
```

or directly the main class, without packaging:

```
mvn clean compile exec:exec -Pclass-exec
```